# Does customizing "::operator new" require special allocators for std containers?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

I have written a memory allocator to solve a problem with the speed of the default one in C++ (mingw).

To do this I've overloaded global new and delete. All the requests i'm getting through are being correctly allocated with memory of the correct sizes but i'm still getting segmentation faults. These faults seem to be about the use of vectors.

I assume these vectors would be covered by the global override of new and delete but I maybe wrong. So what i'm asking is would I need to have an stl allocator that works off of my memory allocator or is it likely some other problem using global new and delete that I have overlooked?

Comment: `new` is generally based on `malloc`, did you try switching to `jemalloc` or `tcmalloc` (disclaimer: no idea whether it works in MinGW).

Comment: By the way, it's neither "overload" nor "override". The correct term is "replace".

Comment: @ceorron Does your allocator use a memory pool that is itself allocated dynamically, using new? Possibly even using vectors? That won't work, and it would explain crashes.

Comment: No the allocator, allocates internally using malloc and a linked list. As I said I don't think this problem is a problem with the allocator.

Comment: Voting to reopen. It is a complete mystery to me why this could be classified as "not a real question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume these vectors would be covered by the global override of new and delete but I maybe wrong. So what i'm asking is would I need to have an stl allocator that works off of my memory allocator or is it likely some other problem using global new and delete that I have overlooked?

The C++ Standard (here from C++11) says about `std::allocator` (the default allocator used for standard containers):

> (§20.6.9/1) Remark: the storage is obtained by calling ::operator new(std::size_t) (18.6.1), but it is unspeciﬁed when or how often this function is called. [...]

So the fact that you didn't implement a special allocator class for use with the vectors is not a problem. The problem is probably caused by something wrong about your definition of the global operator itself, or perhaps about the way you use the vectors. Recommended next steps are:

- Check whether the code works when `::operator new` is not replaced
- Use a debugger to obtain a stack trace of the crash and analyse the stack at that point to obtain clues on what functions are involved in the crash, what the values of local variables at that point is, etc.

Comment: Do you know whether `::operator new[]` could be called ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I also wondered about that. According to the quote from the Standard, `operator new(size_t)` is called; it doesn't mention the array version.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting indeed, though not too surprising I guess seeing how raw storage is allocated.

Comment: In the end your suggestions for what to do next was the sanity check I needed, yes you don't need an allocator for std collections to do this. The problem was actually in mingw/gcc with the calling of constructors of large data structures before the call on main!! This was overcome with a simple "init" function for the allocator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [STL Allocators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement) would need to be implemented for you to control `vector`s allocations